# std::regex with char32_t in microsoft visual studio?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010

Well I'm wondering why this isn't working - and if this is a simple problem from VS 2010;

```
std::basic_regex<char32_t> re;
```

The above line gives a compilation error:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\regex(1975): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::tr1::regex_traits<_Elem>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char32_t
1>          ]
```

And a lot of follow up errors, all in the same line. So is this a problem specific to visual studio 2010 - is there a work around (other than first converting the string to UTF8 and using that as base and then reconverting back to UTF32).

And/or should I use `boost::regex` will I then circumvent this problem?

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits) reference. You have to provide your own specialization for `std::regex_traits<char32_t>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most probably need to use [Boost.Regex with ICU](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu/unicode_types.html)

Example: [icu_example.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/example/snippets/icu_example.cpp)

Or, if you stay on Windows, MFC: [mfc_example.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/example/snippets/mfc_example.cpp)